# Is there a way to get mouse position in opencv without mouse movement or click?

Tags: python, opencv

I need a method to get mouse position without mouse movement or mouse click using OpenCV in python.
`EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` returns the position only when there is movement, but as I mentioned above, I want to get position without movement or click.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand this. If you register a callback for `EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` you can get the current position and store it in a global variable. Then you can get the position as often as you like, say every 50ms on a timer, even without further movement, by looking at the global variable. By definition, the mouse must be still at the last place it was when it last moved if it hasn't moved since.

Comment: I want the position of the mouse on the canvas as soon as the program starts without mouse movement or click so basically 'setMouseCallback()' works only when there is some movement or click but I want the mouse position always even without movement